# Unable to remove react-leaflet Map with MapControl in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I created map legend in Leaflet map using MapControl. Everything working well but when I try to remove Map component I have error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined`  from `MapControl.js`. Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Below is example in codesandbox - after 5 seconds I removed map and changed content.
https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-add-a-legend-to-the-map-using-react-leaflet-forked-if0q4?file=/src/Map.js

Comment: I solve this problem. I moved code from `componentDidMount` in `Legend.js` to method `createLeafletElement`. This method should return `LeafletElement` [github, MapControl class](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/v2.4.0/src/MapControl.js) If someone need this I can send my solution :)